# Download CSV file into controller

Tags: 8, views

I made a view with views data export contrib module, thanks to I download a CSV file of some information, for example, I want to export peoples data in CSV format from a view, as I show with the followed screen:

[image]

Well, I need to download this file, and save it into drupal filesystem, in particular into public file, or attach it to an email, for example. In fact, when I click on path that I defined for the view, I can download the file normally, but when I want to attach it to an email or download it from a controller method, or so on, the file is empty or it is not created.

Views Data Export contrib module doesn't provide drush command to execute the download, and I do not think that is the best method to do this.

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers!  So are you basically asking how to create a managed CSV file from selected rows of a view right? That's a bit broad of a question I guess. You may want to look into the Views Data Export module's code how they are doing it as starting point.

Comment: Thank you so much for the welcome!
Mhmm no, @leymannx, I want to get the file produced by Views Data Export module through the view I defined and attach it to an e-mail, for example.

Comment: That makes it even broader. I'd recommend as first step to create the managed file. But yeah, then your question is: How can I create a CSV from selected view rows and attach it to a mail? What about the mail body, subject and the recipients? Where do they come from?

Comment: Yes, but this module doesn't provide a method to download the file and save it into drupal filesystem. Just this would be great for me, so if you know how to download the file as managed file and save it into my personal folder, called for example public://views_file/ helps me not less. The other question, I think is automatically resolved by the answer of this first question..

Comment: It sounds like you want a cron task that executes this view and then does something with its output (save file). This will not be possible from the Views UI itself. The closest you will get without writing code is using Views Data Export to create the link that will generate the export file upon click, but Views won't attach files to outgoing emails.

Comment: I found the solution with getting the result of the view. In particular, I execute the view and get the result of that, that is printed with CSV formatted way, so I can save the content with the CSV extension. See the main post for the solution.